# Navbar active link animation

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I was wondering how to make this animation in VueJS ?

[image: https://i.imgur.com/JdzAKfX.gifv]

I don't know how to move the component in the DOM.

Thanks

Comment: Look for a lavalamp library. like this one: https://lavalamp.magicmediamuse.com/

Comment: @Niels looks interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like that:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Browse</h1>
    <div class="header">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li
          :class="menuSelected == 'Categories' ? `selected` : ''"
          @click="selectCategories"
        >
          Catetories
        </li>
        <li
          :class="menuSelected == 'LiveChannels' ? `selected` : ''"
          @click="selectLiveChannels"
        >
          Live Channels
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="border" ref="border"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        Filter by
        <input type="text" class="my-input" />
      </label>
      <p>{{ menuSelected }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    menuSelected: 'Categories',
  }),
  methods: {
    selectLiveChannels() {
      this.$refs.border.style.left = '7rem';
      this.menuSelected = 'LiveChannels';
    },
    selectCategories() {
      this.$refs.border.style.left = '0rem';
      this.menuSelected = 'Categories';
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.header {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 1rem 0 0.5rem 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 7rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu li:hover {
  color: purple;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  color: purple;
}

.border {
  background-color: purple;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  left: 0rem;
  height: 0.33rem;
  width: 7rem;
  transition: left 0.3s;
}

.my-input {
  border: 0;
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
</style>
```

This code must be placed in a single file component.

Feel free to change styles and behaviors.

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? Please accept this answer and this will help others people. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I know how to do what you did but I want to animate the purple target by moving it and I don't really know how to

Comment: Ok, I upated my answer. Did this solve your problem?

Comment: There you create use CSS to create the purple target, so one for each element. I want the target move to the other element when clicked. The target CSS will have a transform transition.

Comment: Thanks :) Ameliorated what u made here: https://jsfiddle.net/7dcm1bsj/2/